# protocol associated type typealias assignment compile error

Tags: swift, swift2, protocols

Following code:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    typealias SomeType = Int // used typealias-assignment

    func someFunc(someVar: SomeType)
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    func someFunc(someVar: SomeType) {
        print(someVar)
    }
}
```

gives compile-time error:

> Use of undeclared type 'SomeType'

Adding, say `typealias SomeType = Double`, to the `SomeClass` resolves the error.

The question is, what's the point of *typealias-assignment* part (which is optional btw) of protocol associated type declaration though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the assignment of `Int` to the `typealias` is equal to no assignment because it gets overridden by your conforming type:

```
// this declaration is equal since you HAVE TO provide the type for SomeType
protocol SomeProtocol {
    typealias SomeType

    func someFunc(someVar: SomeType)
}
```

Such an assignment provides a default type for `SomeType` which gets overridden by your implementation in `SomeClass`, but it is especially useful for protocol extensions:

```
protocol Returnable {
    typealias T = Int // T is by default of type Int
    func returnValue(value: T) -> T
}

extension Returnable {
    func returnValue(value: T) -> T {
        return value
    }
}

struct AStruct: Returnable {}

AStruct().returnValue(3) // default signature: Int -> Int
```

You get the function for free only by conforming to the protocol without specifying the type of `T`. If you want to set your own type write `typealias T = String // or any other type` in the struct body.

**Some additional notes about the provided code example**

You solved the problem because you made it explicit which type the parameter has. Swift also infers your used type:

```
class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    func someFunc(someVar: Double) {
        print(someVar)
    }
}
```

So `SomeType` of the protocol is inferred to be `Double`.

Another example where you can see that `SomeType` in the class declaration doesn't refer to to the protocol:

```
class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    typealias Some = Int
    func someFunc(someVar: Some) {
        print(someVar)
    }
}

// check the type of SomeType of the protocol
// dynamicType returns the current type and SomeType is a property of it
SomeClass().dynamicType.SomeType.self // Int.Type
// SomeType gets inferred form the function signature
```

However if you do something like that:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    typealias SomeType: SomeProtocol

    func someFunc(someVar: SomeType)
}
```

`SomeType` has to be of type `SomeProtocol` which can be used for more explicit abstraction and more static code whereas this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func someFunc(someVar: SomeProtocol)
}
```

would be dynamically dispatched.

Comment: Look, I didn't ask anyone to answer why declaring typealias inside the class resolves the error. I had realised that before I created this topic. I asked what is the practical application of typealias assignment inside protocol. To paraphrase, what specific limitations this functionality resolves?

Comment: @mesmerizingsnow That was just additional information. But I also gave the answer: An assignment has no effect on the behavior like no assignment(`typealias SomeType = Int` is equal to `typealias SomeType`)

Comment: I got this answer empirically. Do you have something to back up your answer, say, links to developer.apple.com forums or some quotation from some blog, twitter or something?

Comment: After some research (Unfortunately I've found no documentation about it) an tryouts I found the actual meaning of the assignment (edited my answer). But if you keep your protocol as it is, the assignment is redundant.

Comment: I see your point and you're probably right. I accept your answer as a valid one. Thanks!

Comment: @Qbyte where you give the code example for "Such an assignment provides a default type for SomeType... especially useful for protocol extensions"  ->  this doesn't make any sense, how is this useful for the protocol extension? the extension has no knowledge of the typealias' type, if it did then instead of `return value` in the extension you'd be able to `return value.successor()` (an instance method on `Int`), but this is not possible ("Self.T does not have a member named 'successor'") - note that if you declare the typealias in the protocol like `typealias T: IntegerType` then this will work

Comment: @fqdn You are right. The protocol extension doesn't have knowledge of the actual type (`Int`). Instead it has to treat it as `Any` (in this case). So a default type neither changes the type nor adds some methods/properties to it. If you leave out the assignment you would have to provide the type of `SomeType` in your struct/class/enum declaration which conforms to it (as `typealias`). But not with a default type and the compiler is happy :). That is what I meant by "usefulness".

Answer (score 5):

There is some great information in the documentation on "[associated types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID189)" in protocols.

Their use is abundant throughout the standard library, for an example reference the [SequenceType](http://swiftdoc.org/swift-2/protocol/SequenceType/) protocol, which declares a `typealias` for `Generator` (and specifies that it conforms to `GeneratorType`). This allows the protocol declaration to refer to that aliased type.

In your case, where you used `typealias SomeType = Int`, perhaps what you meant was "*I want SomeType to be constrained to Integer-like behavior because my protocol methods will depend on that constraint*" - in which case, you may want to use `typealias SomeType: IntegerType` in your protocol, and then in your class go on to assign a type to that alias which conforms to `IntegerType`.

**UPDATE**

After opening a bug w/ Apple on this and having had extensive discussion around it, I have come to an understanding of what the base issue is at the heart of this:

***when conforming to a protocol, you cannot directly refer to an associated type that was declared only within that protocol***

*(note, however, that when **extending** a protocol the associated type is available, as you would expect)*

So in your initial code example:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    typealias SomeType = Int
    func someFunc(someVar: SomeType)
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    func someFunc(someVar: SomeType) {  // use of undeclared type "SomeType"
        print(someVar)
    }
}
```

...the error re: "use of undeclared type" is correct, your class `SomeClass` has not declared the type `SomeType`

However, an extension to `SomeProtocol` has access to the associated type, and can refer to it when providing an implementation:

*(note that this requires using a `where` clause in order to define the requirement on the associated type)*

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    typealias SomeType = Int
    func someFunc(someVar: SomeType)
}

extension SomeProtocol where SomeType == Int {
    func someFunc(someVar: SomeType) {
        print("1 + \(someVar) = \(1 + someVar)")
    }
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {}

SomeClass().someFunc(3)  // => "1 + 3 = 4"
```

Comment: In my case I used 'Int' assignment just to test this functionality. I was seating with my laptop reading 'Language Reference' of official Apple 'Swift Programming Guide' reference, got to 'Declaration' section and found protocol declaration link with link to associated type declaration syntax. And there I found that one could use typealias assignment when declaring typealiases. Though it's optional.

Answer (score 1):

There is [great article](http://en.swifter.tips/typealias/) that actually gives you answer for your question. I suggest everyone to read it to get into type-aliases and some more advanced stuff that comes up when you use it.

Citation from website:

> Conceptually, there is no generic protocols in Swift. But by using
>   typealias we can declare a required alias for another type.

Comment: In the article they didn't use typealias assignment. They used type inheritance clause though but this doesn't answer my question.