# Default Type in Swift Protocol Type Aliases Possible?

Tags: swift, generics, struct, protocols, associated-types

I normally wax poetic about the virtues of one programming paradigm or another, but today I've decided to get right to my question. So here I go…

I have 4–5 similar structs. In each one, the first 3 fields are *nearly* identical. I'm storing these structures in an array. Since each struct is its own type, and since generic protocol-oriented programming is all I hear about anymore, I decided to have them all conform to a protocol. Then I can easily hold them in the same array like this: `var tables: [DataHoldable]`.

So, I know I need to create 5 structs, all of which *must* share three members: `format`, `length`, and `language`. Here's a shortened example of what I'm talking about:

```
// Imagine `TableA`, `TableB`, etc.
struct Table[A-D] : DataHoldable {
    var format: UInt16
    var length: UInt16
    var language: UInt16
    ...
}

struct TableE : DataHoldable {
    var format: Int32
    var length: UInt32
    var language: UInt32
    ...
}
```

As you can see, `TableE` has wider integers for all of its fields and its `format` field is signed to top it off.

So, this is where I *thought* the handy `typealias` feature could come into play.

I made a protocol like so:

```
protocol DataHoldable {

    typealias FormatType = UInt16
    typealias LengthType = UInt16
    typealias LangType = UInt16

    var format: FormatType { get }
    var length: LengthType { get }
    var language: LangType { get }

}
```

I thought that by assigning a default type of `UInt16` to the protocol's associated types, I wouldn't have to explicitly state `UInt16` in the first 4 structs, allowing me to bypass a lot of retyping (pun intended). I was thinking it'd be possible to do something like this:

```
struct Table[A-D] : DataHoldable {
    var format: FormatType
    var length: LengthType
    var language: LangType
    ...
}

struct TableE : DataHoldable {
    typealias FormatType = Int32
    typealias LengthType = UInt32
    typealias LangType = UInt32

    var format: FormatType
    var length: LengthType
    var language: LangType
    ...
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be the case, as I started getting error after error, no matter what I did. I even created an extension to the protocol, as I thought one was able to use the default associated type(s) in an extension. However, when doing that, I introduced new scarier errors.

I've tried about 10 different combinations and/or hacks and/or trickery, and nothing seems to work.

So my question is: what's the point of being able to "genericize" code if one can't actually make the code generic? Am I missing something? Any help, thoughts, ideas, possible routes, etc. would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See [this relevant Q & A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562276/protocol-associated-type-typealias-assignment-compile-error): you must provide the types for your typealiases. The typealias assignment (in the protocol) is used mainly to supply default extension methods. (Relevant quote: _"when conforming to a protocol, you cannot directly refer to an associated type that was declared only within that protocol"_, from user fqdn:s answer)

Answer (score 0):

As I've written in my comment, see [this relevant Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562276/protocol-associated-type-typealias-assignment-compile-error) regarding attempting to use a default assignment for associated types (`typealias` here) in a protocol.

> **Quote from [user fqdn:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31567802/4573247)**
>
> *"... when conforming to a protocol, you cannot directly refer to an associated type that was declared only within that protocol*
>
> *(note, however, that when extending a protocol the associated type is available, as you would expect) "*

---

Now, attempting to use default (assigned) associated types is not really the "generic strength of protocols"; rather (as an example, in this case), the possibility to implement default protocol implementations using your associated types, in methods defined in a protocol extension.

```
protocol DataHoldable {
    typealias FormatType
    typealias LengthType
    typealias LangType

    var format: FormatType { get }
    var length: LengthType { get }
    var language: LangType { get }
}

extension DataHoldable {
    func getFormatAndLengthAsTuple() -> (FormatType, LengthType) {
        return(format, length)
    }
}
```

The default method `getFormatAndLengthAsTuple()` will be accessible to any type conforming to the `DataHoldable` protocol. Moreover, the actual type of the typealiases (associated types) `FormatType`, `LengthType` and `LangType` needn't be explicitly stated in the type conformances to `DataHoldable`, it can be *inferred* by the types of properties `format`, `length` and `language`.

```
struct TableA : DataHoldable {
    var format: UInt16      // FormatType inferred to be UInt16
    var length: UInt16      // LengthType inferred to be UInt16
    var language: UInt16    // LangType inferred to be UInt16

    init() {
        format = 1
        length = 2
        language = 3
    }

    // ...
}

struct TableE : DataHoldable {

    var format: Int32       // FormatType inferred to be UInt16
    var length: UInt32      // FormatType inferred to be UInt16
    var language: UInt32    // FormatType inferred to be UInt16

    init() {
        format = 4
        length = 5
        language = 6
    }

    // ...
}
```

And in here lies some of the "generic strength" of protocol and protocol extensions

```
let fooA = TableA()
let fooE = TableE()
print(fooA.getFormatAndLengthAsTuple()) // (1, 2)
print(fooE.getFormatAndLengthAsTuple()) // (4, 5)
```

---

Finally, note that the usage of `typealias T = SomeActualType` in protocol blueprints is quite unusual; a more common approach is to include some *type constraint* on the associated types, `typealias T: SomeTypeConstraint`.

E.g., in your case, it could be appropriate to constrain your associated types to [`IntegerType`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/IntegerType/), allowing you to e.g. use these associated types as keys in a dictionary, since the compiler knows that all types conforming to `IntegerType` also conforms to `Equatable` and `Hashable`).

```
protocol DataHoldable {
    typealias FormatType: IntegerType
    // ...

    var format: FormatType { get }
    var dict : [FormatType:String] { get set }
}

extension DataHoldable {
    mutating func setFormatKeyFooValue() {
        dict[format] = "foo"
    }
}

struct TableA : DataHoldable {
    var format: UInt16 = 42
    var dict : [UInt16:String] = [:]

    // ...
}

var fooA = TableA()
fooA.setFormatKeyFooValue()
print(fooA.dict) // [42: "foo"]
```